# Insert command does not take any effect

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I need to insert data into a data base using Oracle SQL in Java, but when I call the "insertOriginalSpreadsheet" function it does not throw any exception, and the application does not show anything, and the data in the data base is never inserted.

Here's the function:

```
public static void insertOriginalSpreadsheet(Spreadsheet originalSpreadsheet) {

        try(PreparedStatement spreadsheetInsert = DBConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO EXTRATO_ORIGINAL (ID_CLIENTE, ID_PROVEDORES, CRIADO, ATUALIZADO, ATUALIZADO, VALOR, ORIGEM, DESTINO, TIPO_CREDITO, DATA_TRANSACAO, DOCUMENTO_REFERENCIA, COMENTARIO_OPERADOR, AGENCIA, CONTA, DESCRICAO) values (?, ?, sysdate, sysdate, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

            for(int i = 0; i < originalSpreadsheet.valor.size(); i++) {
                spreadsheetInsert.setLong(1, originalSpreadsheet.IDCliente);
                spreadsheetInsert.setLong(2, originalSpreadsheet.IDProvedores);
                spreadsheetInsert.setLong(3, Long.parseLong(originalSpreadsheet.valor.get(i)));
                spreadsheetInsert.setString(4, originalSpreadsheet.origem.get(i));
                spreadsheetInsert.setString(5, originalSpreadsheet.destino.get(i));
                spreadsheetInsert.setString(6, originalSpreadsheet.tipoCredito.get(i));
                spreadsheetInsert.setDate(7, Date.valueOf(originalSpreadsheet.dataTransacao.get(i)));
                spreadsheetInsert.setString(8, originalSpreadsheet.documentoReferencia.get(i));
                spreadsheetInsert.setString(9, originalSpreadsheet.comentarioOperador.get(i));
                spreadsheetInsert.setString(10, originalSpreadsheet.agencia);
                spreadsheetInsert.setString(11, originalSpreadsheet.conta);
                spreadsheetInsert.setString(12, originalSpreadsheet.descricao.get(i));
                spreadsheetInsert.execute();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.print( e.getMessage() );

            System.out.print("Reiniciando conexão com o banco : ");
            DBConnection = null;
            setDataBaseConfig();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
```

Note: when using the debugger it does not reach any breakpoint anywhere placed inside the function.

Note 2: it was working before, now it's not.

Comment: A missing `commit()` maybe?

Comment: I tried to insert the commit() function before, it did not work either.

Comment: It looks like the Java Compiler is skipping the function.

Comment: Maybe you don't have any data to insert (eg originalSpreadsheet.valor.size() is 0). I suggest that you step through your code with a debugger, and otherwise post a [mcve].

Comment: I do have data to insert. I looked over the data base and a SQLRecoverableException was thrown.

Comment: So what is the error message of that Exception? You also state in your question that **no** exception was thrown. And now suddenly you see one.